# unknown luaJIT command or jit.* modules not installed

Tags: lua, cocos2d-iphone, luajit

I'm programing a quick-cocos project.
For some reason, there are multiple cocos2d-x engines in my mac. And the engine I use is **copied** from another developer and I used setup_mac.sh to install the engine. The version of the engine might be 3.6(I'm not sure, the name of engine dir is "Quick-Cocos2dx-Community")

I'm trying to package the lua file by using the build.sh.
"unknown luaJIT command or jit.* modules not installed" error showed out.
I've tracked the code and find the error should happen when the system is trying running the code below.

```
MY_ENGINE_ROOT/Quick-Cocos2dx-Community/quick/bin/mac/luajit -b "MY_PROJECT_DIR/app/ad_dialog/AdDialog.lua" "MY_PROJECT_DIR/app/ad_dialog/AdDialog.bytes"
```

I bet it should be the error of environment variable. But I don't know where the error should be.

It will work when I use build.sh in my quick-cocos2d-x-2.2.6. But the file it packed cannot be used in my new project. There will be a pre-compile error when the program load the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution now. After I installed the engine, I have to install luajit which is in the engine dir manually. That will overwrite the old luajit in my mac. There are docs in

```
MY_ENGINE_ROOT/Quick-Cocos2dx-Community/external/lua/luajit/src/doc/install.html
```